# Flutter Error: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, null

I want to develop the banking app in flutter.
But I get this error: Null check operator used on a null value
I tried "flutter channel stable" but its not work and also tried '!' operator (as you can see in the code) but its not work... :(

Plese help me..
Note: Container widget is very long that's why I didn't choose to copy..

```
  Widget projectWidget() {
        return FutureBuilder<List<Histories>>(
            future: dbHelper.getHistories(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.length > 0) return Container();
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Histories histories = snapshot.data![index];
                  return Container();
                },
              );
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your if statement, and in that way you try to access the data when it still don't exist, try something like this

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Histories>>(
        future: dbHelper.getHistories(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Histories>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)  {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Histories histories = snapshot.data![index];
                      return Container();
                },
              );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            print('error');
            return Text('error');
          }
        });
```

or you can substitute this `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)` with your if statement like this

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Histories>>(
        future: dbHelper.getHistories(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Histories>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.length > 0)  {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Histories histories = snapshot.data![index];
                      return Container();
                },
              );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            print('error');
            return Text('error');
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the builder else condition is wrong. With the current code even if the snapshot has not data it will try to call `snapshot.data!.length` that's what causing null error.

```
Widget projectWidget() {
        return FutureBuilder<List<Histories>>(
            future: dbHelper.getHistories(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.length > 0) 
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Histories histories = snapshot.data![index];
                  return Container();
                },
              );

               else 
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            });
      }
```